# How to aggregate generated test result with nosetest and multiprocessing?

Tags: python, aggregate, nose, nosetests

I’m using [nose](/questions/tagged/nose) to run my tests.
Most of my test use yield, eg:

```
@attr(id='666')
def test_even(self):
    """test even"""
    for i in range(20):
        yield eq_, i%2 , 0, 'failed for %d' %i
```

out of this test spawn 20 tests, from other tests more `N` tests spawn.
and it looks something like this:

```
test even ... ok
test even ... FAIL
test even ... ok
test even ... FAIL
test even ... ok
.....
another test ... ok
another test ... FAIL
.....
```

My problem is that all the tests are printed flat and not aggregated like this:

```
test even:
    test even ... ok
    test even ... FAIL
    test even ... ok
    test even ... FAIL
    test even ... ok
    ......
another teset:
    another test ... ok         
    another test ... FAIL
    ......
```

I did manage to achieve that by writing my own plugin and without running the multiprocessing plugin.
* I know that multiprocessing plugin don’t play well with others.

Is there a way to achieve this behaviour while using multiprocessing plugin as well?